# Success or FailureRedirect not working - Passportjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

Here below is my local strategy which now runs fine for me.

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
    User.getUserByUsername(username, function(err, user){
      if(err) console.log(err);
      if(!user){
        console.log("No user");
        done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown User'});}
        console.log("success");
        done(null, true, username);

 User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
      if(err) console.log(err);
      if(isMatch){
        console.log("There is a match");
        done(null, true, user);
      } else {
        console.log("Invalid password");
        done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid password'});
      }});
   });
  }));
```

However after a username and corresponding password are found in the database I would like to redirect to a different page. I have the passport.authenticate() method setup in my post route however after the username and password are found in the database the page reloads for minutes until it returns a webpage not found error neither the failureRedirect or successRedirect routes work

```
router.post("/users/login",
    passport.authenticate("local", {
        successRedirect:"/",
         failureRedirect:"/login",
            failureFlash:true}, function(err, user, info){
        if(err){console.log(err);}
        console.log(user)
        console.log(info)
    }), 
  function(req, res){
        res.redirect("/");
  });
```

Comment: If you `return` from a function, no code after the `return` statement is executed. That's the whole point of a `return` statement.

Comment: Basically remove your `else` code before you call `User.comparePassword`

Comment: Moreover you are executing the the `done()` callback in both the `if` and the `else`. So coupled with the existing `returns` there simply is no way the code can execute any further.

Comment: Thanks guys, this helped!

Comment: BTW I think the second parameter of  __User.comparePassword__ is wrong, you should use user.password (in lower case)

Comment: Everythings good now, on the submission of my form however the failure or successRedirect options don't work in the post route